# Can I use Entity Framework with a non-relational SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, non-relational-database

I am working on a project with someone who has developed a desktop app for people who run charity voucher companies. They have customers who have accounts, who put money in their accounts, and who write charity vouchers (bit like cheques) to charities.

He wants me to write a web site where both charities and customers can log in and see details of their accounts, vouchers issued, etc.

As most of the data will be coming from his app to my web site, we agreed to use his primary key IDs in my database, so it will be easy to match up the data.

We're quite well into it, and it I've discovered that he is a staunch opponent of relational databases. His database doesn't have any foreign reference keys at all, just IDs in tables. He does individual queries on each table to see if the related data is there.

I want to use Entity Framework, but am not sure if I can, as I can't be sure that the data he sends me will be complete. For example, he might send me details of a voucher, which will have a customer ID and a charity ID, but the customer may not have been sent, so the customer ID on the voucher won't exist in the customers table.

Any ideas what I can do? I can't have foreign links between my tables, as this will throw errors whenever it comes across incomplete data, but if I don't have any links, then I've lost the whole benefit of using EF.

My only thought so far is to leave the tables unrelated, and then add partial classes for the entities, with properties that will look like navigation properties, but that will check to see if the "foreign" data is there, and if so, return it.

This might work, but seems like a lot of effort. Anyone any better suggestions as to how I handle this situation?

Comment: *bat him round the head with a soggy fish until he realises how totally awesome and uber cool relational databases are and how crap not having one is?

Comment: EF works fine with out relationships. If your data model is just a collection of unrelated tables what else can you do ? Beyond soggy fish?

Comment: Steven, I've had plenty of arguments with him, but it's a waste of time. I need to see how best I can handle things now.

Comment: Phil, I know EF will work, in that it will create the objects for me, but then I lose all the benefits of navigation properties and so on. As I said, I can simulate this by adding my own, but it means a lot of work. I was hoping there would be a better way.

Comment: No one any ideas? I tried adding my own navigation properties, but I ended up having to access the context in my entity classes, and as I'd split the entities into their own class library, I ended up with circular references. I can't see any way of doing this. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I asked the question again (phrased more clearly), and got a good answer which works. See here for details... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358043/can-entity-framework-be-used-when-relational-data-is-missing

Comment: maybe not now, but in future. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/05/19/ef7-new-platforms-new-data-stores.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but since I stumbled across this question, it might be useful for others.

Microsoft recently announced that EF Core (within ASP.NET Core 2.1) [will have a provider](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/02/02/entity-framework-core-2-1-roadmap/) for [Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction):

> Cosmos DB provider preview: We have been developing an EF Core
>   provider for the DocumentDB API in Cosmos DB. This is the first
>   document database provider we have produced, and the learnings from
>   this exercise are going to inform improvements in the design of the
>   subsequent release after 2.1. The current plan is to publish an early
>   preview of the Cosmos DB provider in the 2.1 timeframe.

**NOTE:** A short video containing major features to be delivered with ASP.NET Core 2.1 can be seen [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/02/asp-net-core-2-1-roadmap/).